# Text in Textbox repeating after appending new textbox on IE browser

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

When I first put any text on the first textbox its good, but once I add a new textbox whatever is in the first textbox it copies to the next append textbox. This is only happening on IE(testing with IE 11).

Since IE is our main browser we use.

How do i fix this issue with to get it to work on IE?

I made a https://jsfiddle.net/Ltzmu3p6/1/ to test it out, In my original form which is bigger all the other  input text have to issues.

```
  <textarea rows="5" cols="90" id="customFields_name" class="employemnt_duties"  name="employemnt_duties_1"  ></textarea>

<script>
//for the company 
  $(".companyCF3").click(function(){
    var firstRow = $("#customFields_emp > tbody:first");
    $("#customFields_emp").append('<tbody>' + firstRow.html() + '</tbody>');
    //Process data
    $("#customFields_emp > tbody:last").find('.companyCF3').remove();


    $("#customFields_emp > tbody:last").find('.lastitem').append('<span style="float:right">   <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF3">Remove</a> </span>');

    var position_emp = parseInt($("#totalEmployment").val())+1;

    $("#customFields_emp > tbody:last").find('.employemnt_duties').attr('name', 'employemnt_duties_' + position_emp.toString());



    $("#totalEmployment").val(parseInt($("#totalEmployment").val())+1);
  });
  $("#customFields_emp").on('click','.remCF3',function(){
      $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().remove();
      $("#totalEmployment").val(parseInt($("#totalEmployment").val())-1);
  });


</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to `clone` your `firstRow` and then find `textarea` within it before adding it as `html` for your new row.

Below is 2 lines of changes you might want to do.

```
var firstRow = $("#customFields_emp > tbody:first").clone();  
firstRow.find("textarea").text("");
```

**[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/Ltzmu3p6/2/)**